# Using Angular 2 with VS2015 Update 2 - getting npm -not installed error

Tags: angularjs, node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-1.0

I created an empty core 1.0 web app and added a package.json file copying the angular2 quick start package.json lines [from this url](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html).

I keep getting the message Dependencies - not installed and npm - not installed.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Do I have to actually install node.js on my PC in order for Visual Studio to be able to use it? Bower works perfectly...

Comment: What happens if you right click on npm and select "Restore Packages"?

Comment: I seem to be having the same issue

Comment: @WernerCD I ended up installing node.js on my machine and restarted Visual Studio. Make a change to the packages.json file and they will all install.

Comment: Additionally something is very strange with the new @Syntax that the Angular 2 QuickStart uses in package.json and VS2015 npm. Angular2 doesn't seem to be getting installed into the node_modules folder.

Comment: @Blake Did you use exact package.json from quickstart. After installing separate node.js, I am still getting npm -not installed message.

Comment: You do not need to explicitly install node.js because [Visual Studio makes its own installation of node.js](http://jameschambers.com/2015/09/upgrading-npm-in-visual-studio-2015/) which it uses internally to support Bower and npm.  In my case, I do have node.js explicitly installed, but I still have the same problem you do.

Comment: Fortunately, despite the error shown in the VS "solution explorer" windows, my solution compiles and executes correctly.  You should study that link I provided, in case you have conflicting installs of node.js.

Comment: This worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/38768272/20126

Answer (score 2):

This issue is being tracked here:
https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/479

Repointing Visual Studio to a different `npm` path will likely not make a difference - Visual Studio still seems to interpret a dependency on a package not supported on Windows as a breaking issue.

This is an IDE issue only. **You can still build and run without resolving this problem.**

But if you prefer to get rid of the `not installed` indicator, identify and remove the offending package then manually delete the `node_modules` folder, and re-save `package.json`.