# Dependencies - not installed error (npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents)

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, npm

I am trying to get webpack to work in Visual Studio, but keep getting the `Dependencies - not installed` problem. I get this error in the output:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.15: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

I've read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949833/dependencies-not-installed-in-visual-studio) and Scott Hanselman's solution in [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudio2015FixingDependenciesNpmNotInstalledFromFseventsWithNodeOnWindows.aspx). I.e. I have installed latest node (7.0.0) + npm (3.10.8) and set the Visual Studio to use my node installation (that is definietely used since I see this in output: `"C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD" install`).

So I followed it all, but the thing is: I still get this stupid `not installed` warning in Visual Studio. Am I doing something wrong or it was working in one of the versions, but not working anymore with latest node and nmp?

Comment: It's just a warning, as that module is not compatible with Windows. You can safely ignore it. It's optional.

Comment: Well, it's kind of annoying to see it in the middle of your project with a warning sign + I will never notice if there is a more serious problem happening.

Comment: Yes. That is true. Also, you will often see a disconcerting number of warnings about deprecated versions because not all modules keep their dependencies up to date. It's just one of those annoying things.

Comment: This is a seriously annoying warning when using Visual Studio, just spend 2 hours to fix this non problem.

Comment: You have the error in npm itself, so it's not quite Visual Studio problem, but it's kind of more annoying in VS :)

Comment: I am also facing this same issue in NETBeans IDE 8.2. when i was creating Angular Js Project and trying to install npm and install bower.....if anybody have solution....PLZ reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a warning that `**fseventsd**`.

its not an error.

its a MAC OS Specified, running on **windows** or **`Linux`** show this warning,this the only reason it is showing this warning, you can skip it..

Answer (score 0):

Use *--no-optional* on all environments excepts OSX effectively disabling the cause of the warning.

> npm install --no-optional

Also you can change the log level to *error* so that you won't see warning.

Comment: I don't think that disabling the warning is any solution to the problem which is... the problem behind the warning. If the OP didn't care about the underlying cause he probably would not ask the question. This content could belong in a comment but it is not an answer.